# error: Can not set final int field java.lang.Integer.value to java.lang.Class

Tags: java

I'm new to java and currently using practicing Reflection.

I have this code:

```
try {
    Class<?> c = Integer.class;
    System.out.println("Name: " + c.getName());     
    System.out.println("Super Class: " + c.getSuperclass().getName());

    Class[] cl = c.getInterfaces();
    System.out.println("Interfaces list: ");
    for(Class cls: cl)
    {
        System.out.println(cls.getName() + ", ");
    }

    System.out.println("");
    int i = c.getModifiers();
    System.out.println("Access modifiers: " + Modifier.toString(i));

    //-----------
    System.out.println("\nMETHODS");        
    Method[] ms = c.getDeclaredMethods();
    for(Method m: ms)
    {
        System.out.println("Name: "+ m.getName());

    }       

    //------------
    System.out.println("\nFIELDS");
    Field [] flds = c.getDeclaredFields();
    for(Field f: flds)
    {
        System.out.println("Name: "+ f.getName());
        System.out.println("Data type: " + f.getType().getName());
         i = c.getModifiers();
        System.out.println("Acc modifiers: " + Modifier.toString(i));

         f.setAccessible(true); 
         Object value = f.get(c);
         if (value != null) 
         {
            System.out.println(f.getName() + "=" + value);
         }
        System.out.println("--------------");
    }

    }
    catch(Throwable e)
    {
        System.out.println("error: " + e.getMessage());

    }


}
```

However, it gives me error for field 'value' which is mentioned in the title. Kindly explain the error, and also tell why do we have to write ' f.setAccessible(true); ' (I saw over the internet) What is its purpose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expected parameter by the `Field.get(Object obj)` has to be an instance of the class this field is from. In this case, it has to be an instance of `Integer` and you're using an instance of `Class<Integer>` hence the error.

`setAccessible(true)` is used so that the field can be accessed even if it is inaccessible `private` or `protected`.